# Jquery data table with knockoutjs ,requirejs and mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, requirejs

I am using Knockoutjs ,requirejs and mvc4 for building a web application.I have a 
company list want to show it in data table
My Common.js is given below:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.8.2",
        "jqueryui": "jquery-ui-1.8.24",
        "jqdatatable": "jquery.dataTables",
        "bootstrapdatatable": "dataTables.bootstrap",
        "KO": "knockout-2.2.0"
    },
    shim: {
        "jqdatatable": "jquery.dataTables",
        "bootstrapdatatable": "dataTables.bootstrap"
    }
});
```

My CompanyGrid.js is given below:

```
define(["jquery", "jqdatatable", "bootstrapdatatable","KO"], function ($,ko) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var urlPath = window.location.pathname; 
        ko.applyBindings(CompanyListVM);
        CompanyListVM.getComapanies();

        var CompanyListVM = {
            Company: ko.observableArray([]),
            getComapanies: function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/Company/FetchCompanies',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.Company(data);
                        ShowGrid();
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            },
        };



    }





    );
}



);


function ShowGrid() {

    (function ($) {
        $("#liCompanyList").addClass("active");
        $("#liHome").removeClass("active");
        $("#liUserManagement").removeClass("active");
        $("#liReport").removeClass("active");
        $('#example').dataTable();
    }(jQuery));


}



//Model
function Company(data) {

    this.CompName = ko.observable(data.CompName);
    this.CompLanguage = ko.observable(data.CompLanguage);
    this.CompEmail1 = ko.observable(data.CompEmail1);
    this.CreatedBy = ko.observable(dat.CreatedBy);
}
```

This is showing company list.But I want to show another grid which shows users list.I have written the same function using necessary changes.The code is give for Usergrid.js.

```
define(["jquery", "jqdatatable", "bootstrapdatatable", "KO"], function ($, ko) {
    $(document).ready(function () {


        ko.applyBindings(person);
        ko.applyBindings(UserListVM);
        UserListVM.getUsers();
        var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
        var UserListVM = {
            User: ko.observableArray([]),
            getUsers: function () {
                var self = this;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/UserManagement/FetchUsers',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        self.User(data);
                        ShowGrid();
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            },
        };



    }





    );






}



);


function ShowUserGrid() {

    (function ($) {
        $("#liCompanyList").addClass("active");
        $("#liHome").removeClass("active");
        $("#liUserManagement").removeClass("active");
        $("#liReport").removeClass("active");
        $('#tblUserList').dataTable();
    }(jQuery));


}



//Model
function User(data) {

    this.Usr_Id = ko.observable(data.Usr_Id);
    this.Usr_Name = ko.observable(data.Usr_Name);
    this.Usr_Email = ko.observable(data.Usr_Email);

}
```

But this time user grid is not coming.The webconsole showing the following error **"TypeError: ko is undefined"**

Please Help me I am very new to knockout.js.

Answer (score 0):

You are using require.js and your parameters do not match.

```
define(["jquery", "jqdatatable", "bootstrapdatatable", "KO"], function ($, ko) {
```

`jquery` is loading into `$`,

`jqdatatable` is loading into `ko`,

Comment: Thanks. But my doubt is that it is working perfectly in companygrid. js.it is showing error only in usergrid. js.please help me and clear my doubt